# Resolving an SQL error for INSERT INTO

Tags: php, sql

Could anyone have a look at this echo'd SQL query and tell me what could possibly cause an error please?

The following is the error I recieve;

```
Database query died: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near ') VALUES ('test', 'testcompany', 'test', 'test',
 'test', 'test', '123', '123', '' at line 1
```

The next is the SQL query I echo'd back for testing.

```
INSERT INTO associate_users (
    contactName, company, address1, address2, address3, postcode, 
    telephone, fax, email, type, products, primaryMarket, secondaryMarket,
    selling, employees, years, website, credit, deals, userLevel, 
    regDate, live, 
) VALUES (
    'test', 'testcompany', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test',
    '123', '123', 'tester@aol.com', 'Sole Trader', 'Desktops',
    'Consumer', 'Consumer', 'Telesales', '11', '11', 
    'http://www.foo-bar.co.uk', '0', '0', '1', '2011-03-02-15:57', '0',
)
```

I really cannot understand what the problem is,

Appologies in advance if I have failed to post important code or report information in this original post, if any is missing to aide the solution please dont hesitate to ask.

Thanks in advance,

Dan Wrigley.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response, I cannot believe I missed that :( ah well good to have a great community to back you up when your brain and eyes fail you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the last comma (replace `'2011-03-02-15:57', '0', )` with `'2011-03-02-15:57', '0')`

Answer (score 4):

There's an extra comma in your fields list:

```
... userLevel, regDate, live, ) VALUES ('test', 'testcom ...
                            ^--- here
```

and in the values list:

```
... '0', )
       ^-- here
```

looks like some key/value pair isn't getting inserted properly, or you're generating the field list dynamically and forgot to remove the final comma.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have extra commas at the end of the statement.

```
                V                            V    
...regDate, live, )...'2011-03-02-15:57', '0', )
                ^                            ^
```

Should be

```
...regDate, live)...'2011-03-02-15:57', '0')
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma after `live, )`  -> it should be `live)`

Same for `'0', )` -> should be `'0')`

Answer (score 2):

You have a trailing comma at the end of the fields list.

```
..., regDate, live, ) VALUES ('test', ...
                  ^--- Remove this comma
```

You also have a trailing comma after your `VALUES`.

```
VALUES(..., '2011-03-02-15:57', '0', )
                                   ^---- Remove this comma too
```